# cut that returns guaranteed number of bins

Tags: r

I'd like to do a cut with a guaranteed number of levels returned.  So i'd like to take any vector of cumulative percentages and get a cut into deciles.  I've tried using cut and it works well in most situations, but in cases where there are deciles that have a large percentages it fails to return the desired number of unique cuts, which is 10.  Any ideas on how to ensure that the number of cuts is guaranteed to be 10?

In the included example there is no occurrance of decile 7.

```
> (x <- c(0.04,0.1,0.22,0.24,0.26,0.3,0.35,0.52,0.62,0.66,0.68,0.69,0.76,0.82,1.41,6.19,9.05,18.34,19.85,20.5,20.96,31.85,34.33,36.05,36.32,43.56,44.19,53.33,58.03,72.46,73.4,77.71,78.81,79.88,84.31,90.07,92.69,99.14,99.95))
 [1]  0.04  0.10  0.22  0.24  0.26  0.30  0.35  0.52  0.62  0.66  0.68  0.69  0.76  0.82  1.41  6.19  9.05 18.34 19.85 20.50 20.96 31.85 34.33
[24] 36.05 36.32 43.56 44.19 53.33 58.03 72.46 73.40 77.71 78.81 79.88 84.31 90.07 92.69 99.14 99.95
> (cut(x,seq(0,max(x),max(x)/10),labels=FALSE))
 [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  3  3  4  4  4  4  5  5  6  6  8  8  8  8  8  9 10 10 10 10
> (as.integer(cut2(x,seq(0,max(x),max(x)/10))))
 [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  3  3  4  4  4  4  5  5  6  6  8  8  8  8  8  9 10 10 10 10
> (findInterval(x,seq(0,max(x),max(x)/10),rightmost.closed=TRUE,all.inside=TRUE))
 [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  3  3  4  4  4  4  5  5  6  6  8  8  8  8  8  9 10 10 10 10
```

I would like to get 10 approximately equally sized intervals, sized in such a way that I am assured of getting 10.  cut et al gives 9 bins with this example, i want 10.  So I'm looking for an algorithm that would recognize that the break between [58.03,72.46],73.4 is large.  Instead of assigning to bins 6,8,8 it would assign these cases to bins 6,7,8.

Comment: Use quantile to identify the true deciles?

Comment: perhaps `cut2` from Hmisc package has what your after? I think it's the `g=` parameter FWIW

Comment: Did you actually even _try_ `cut2`? Because for me it give me ten intervals, with at least one observation in each interval.

Answer (score 4):

```
xx <- cut(x, breaks=quantile(x, (1:10)/10, na.rm=TRUE) )
table(xx)
#------------------------
    xx
(0.256,0.58] (0.58,0.718] (0.718,6.76]  (6.76,20.5] 
           4            4            4            4 
 (20.5,35.7]  (35.7,49.7]  (49.7,75.1]  (75.1,85.5] 
           3            4            4            4 
  (85.5,100] 
           4
```

Comment: quantile gives bins with an approximately equal number of observations.  i'd like approximately equally sized intervals instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
numBins = 10
cut(x, breaks = seq(from = min(x), to = max(x), length.out = numBins+1))
```

Output:

```
...
...
...
10 Levels: (0.04,10] (10,20] (20,30] (30,40] (40,50] (50,60] ... (90,100]
```

This will make 10 bins that are approximately equally spaced. Note, that by changing the `numBins` variable, you may obtain any number of bins that are approximately equally spaced.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand what you need, but if you drop the `labels=FALSE` and use `table` to make a frequency table of your data, you will get the number of categories desired:

```
> table(cut(x, breaks=seq(0, 100, 10)))

(0,10]  (10,20]  (20,30]  (30,40]  (40,50]  (50,60]  (60,70]  (70,80]  (80,90] (90,100] 
   17        2        2        4        2        2        0        5        1        4
```

Notice that there are is no data in the 7th category, `(60,70]`.

Comment: I would like there to be atleast one occurrance in each bin.  Having no occurances of the 7th bin is what i'd like to remedy.

Comment: This seems like a strange problem you're trying to solve. For example, how would you deal with a bimodal data where there is no density in the middle?

Answer (score -1):

What is the problem you are trying to solve?   If you don't want quantiles, then your cutpoints are pretty much arbitrary, so you could just as easily create ten bins by sampling without replacement from your original dataset.  I realize that's an absurd method, but I want to make a point: you may be way off track but we can't tell because you haven't explained what you intend to do with your bins.  Why, for example, is it so bad that one bin has no content?